# How to get Python's optparser to see flags in the form -vs

Tags: python, optparse

I am using optparse to process arguments and options and then generate a command to execute another program.

I need optparse to recognize undefined flags/options without throwing an error so I can pass them on the program I am calling. I did it by subclassing OptionParser:

```
class IFTOptionParser(optparse.OptionParser):

    def _process_args(self, largs, rargs, values):
        while rargs:
            try:
                optparse.OptionParser._process_args(self,largs,rargs,values)
            except (optparse.BadOptionError,optparse.AmbiguousOptionError), e:
                largs.append(e.opt_str)
```

But this doesn't work when I pass in a flag like this:
$ foo -vs

It just passes along "-v"

If I go into _process_args, and print out e.opt_str, I get "-v".

Comment: What about passing '--vs'. Single minus arguments are supposed to be single character followed by a value.

Comment: If you can use `argparse`, this is precisely what [`nargs=argparse.REMAINDER`](http://docs.python.org/2.7/library/argparse.html#nargs) is designed for.

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling the answer was to use argparse. I didn't want to have to change the code though.

Comment: "Deprecated since version 2.7: The `optparse` module is deprecated and will not be developed further; development will continue with the `argparse` module"